# Not able to connect Hive from Hue

Tags: ssl, hive, cloudera-cdh, hue

I have a cloudera setup and in it I have enabled the SSL for hive and also enabled hue TLS/SSL Communication with HiveServer2 in hue.ini conf file.

After the changes has been done, trying to connect to Hive from hue then, the following error is being displayed 
"**Certificate error with remote host: hostname 'quickstart.cloudera' doesn't match u'cm01.example.com**'".

Hive Configuration:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.use.SSL</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>enable/disable SSL </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.keystore.path</name>
  <value>/opt/cloudera/security/jks/cmhost-keystore.jks</value>
  <description>keystore-file-path</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.keystore.password</name>
  <value>xyz</value>
  <description>keystore password</description>
</property>
```

Hue Configuration:

```
# SSL communication enabled for this server.
enabled=true

# Path to Certificate Authority certificates.
cacerts=/etc/hue/cmhost.pem

# Path to the private key file.
## key=/etc/hue/key.pem

# Path to the public certificate file.
## cert=/etc/hue/cert.pem

# Choose whether Hue should validate certificates received from the   server.
validate=true
```

Comment: it seems like the domain name for the certificate is not matching with your actual domain. However, it should give you a warning on web browser. could you put a screenshot?

Comment: Hi Gaurang Shah, thanks for your reply. Yes, the domain names where different. While creating a key-store.jks file, domain which I have provided is different from the cloudera domain name. After updating the keystore.jks file I'm able to connect to the Hive from Hue.